# appendTo() and append() works, appendChild() does not

Tags: javascript, jquery

As part of a drag-and-drop file upload interface, `showImage` is called when a file is dropped on the target container. `showImage` checks that the file is an image, reads the file, creates a new `Image` object, sets the dropped image file's data as the `src`, and inserts the new element into the DOM.

For DOM insertion, calling jQuery's `appendTo` or `append` works, but the native method `appendChild` returns the error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`. What is the reason for this?

```
var showImage = function(droppedImg) {
    var imageType = /image.*/;

    if (droppedImg.type.match(imageType)) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            if (e.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) {
                newImg = new Image();
                newImg.onload = function(e) {
                    if (e.target.readyState == Image.DONE) {

                        //No DOM insertion. Throws this error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
                        var dropTarg = document.querySelectorAll('.drop-container');
                        dropTarg.appendChild(newImg); 


                        //Image inserted into DOM
                        $('.drop-container').append(newImg); 
                        //Image inserted into DOM
                        $(newImg).appendTo('.drop-container'); 

                    }
                };
                newImg.src = reader.result;
            }
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(droppedImg);
    }
};
```

Comment: `$('.drop-container').append(newImg);` and `$(newImg).appendTo('.drop-container');` is jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`querySelectorAll()` returns a node list. To get the first element, access it by index:

```
var dropTarg = document.querySelectorAll('.drop-container')[0];
dropTarg.appendChild(newImg);
```

Some error handling to make sure it found something would probably be in order.

Comment: Important point:  `querySelectorAll` returns a [live Node List](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) which is *array-like* in that it has a `length` property, but not actually an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
querySelectorAll()
```

always returns  live Node List  which is array-like , so you have to use either `.each()` or a `for loop` , or specify the index of the element you are targetting.

Comment: Important point:  `querySelectorAll` returns a [live Node List](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) which is *array-like* in that it has a `length` property, but not actually an array.