# appendChild error in JQuery, but appendTo works fine

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is an answer to this question here
[Uncaught Type Error in appendChild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23389683/appendto-and-append-works-appendchild-does-not)
but is not relevant to my use case here as I am not selecting a nodeList, but simply putting one element in a variable.

In the following JQuery snippet, I am getting that same error using appendChild but appendTo works just fine. I'd love to know why that is.

```
function handleImageFiles(files) {
        var container = $("#imageGallery");
        container.innerHtml = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            var filename = file.name;

            var photoDiv = $("<div>", { id: "file" + i, 'class': "col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb" });
                container.appendChild(photoDiv);
               //photoDiv.appendTo(container);

           //rest of code
}
```

container is a valid object, but container.appendChild(photoDiv) is throwing

> Uncaught TypeError: container.appendChild is not a function

I cant understand why that is given both container and photoDiv are valid objects and photoDiv.appendTo(container) works just fine.

Comment: @Kevin B...not a duplicate if you read the post I referenced, which is the same as you noted. "This question was marked as an exact duplicate"...clearly not.

Comment: except... it's identical. Your code doesn't work for the same reason the dupe didn't. And the solution is the same. Either use a jquery method or unwrap the dom node from the jquery object.

Comment: @Kevin B...wrong, he was trying to use appendChild passing a string, which isn't valid, not the case in my example

Comment: Not enough of a difference to matter to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery does not have a function called `appendChild` (only DOM elements have it). What you're looking for is [**`append`**](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

Change: `container.appendChild(photoDiv);` to: `container.append(photoDiv);`.

**Note:** jQuery does not have a property called `innerHTML` as well, it has a function called [**`html`**](http://api.jquery.com/html/) that acheives the same. And if you want to empty the element use [**`empty`**](http://api.jquery.com/empty/).

Comment: ...no innerHtml? Intellisense shows that as a valid method off container. I will use append.

Comment: @dinotom it allowing it because `container` is an object and you're adding a property `innerHTML` to that object. The effect you expect won't happen. It's like: `var obj = {}; obj.innerHTML = "";` which is absolutly fine, but has no effect on DOM elements.

Comment: ...thank you for the clarification on that

Comment: probably the same guy who marked as duplicate when totally different scenario

Comment: Yeah! It's him alright. He's done it before.